# Base64 encode differences in BCrypt implemenations

Tags: code-review, bcrypt, c, encoding

I was reading the source code of several BCrypt implementations and found that two common c implementations have a difference in their base64 encoding of the salt.

What is the effect, if any, of the differences on line 18 and line 22 of the two base64 encoding implementations below.

**Original implementation**

```
/**
 * Original BCrypt implementation
 * http://mail-index.netbsd.org/tech-crypto/2002/05/24/msg000204.html
 */
function encodeBase64_a($input) {
    $itoa64 = './ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    $i = 0;
    $output = '';
    while (true) {
        $c1 = ord($input{$i++});
        $output .= $itoa64{$c1 >> 2};
        $c1 = ($c1 & 0x03) << 4;
        if ($i >= 16) {
            $output .= $itoa64{$c1};
            break;
        }
        $c2 = ord($input{$i++});
        $c1 |= $c2 >> 4 & 0x0f;
        $output .= $itoa64{$c1};
        $c1 = ($c2 & 0x0f) << 2;
        $c2 = ord($input{$i++});
        $c1 |= $c2 >> 6 & 0x03;
        $output .= $itoa64{$c1};
        $output .= $itoa64{$c2 & 0x3f};
    }
    return $output;
}
```

**OpenWall implementation**

```
/**
 * OpenWall implementation
 * crypt_blowfish-1.2
 * source: http://www.openwall.com/crypt/
 */
function encodeBase64_b($input) {
    $itoa64 = './ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    $i = 0;
    $output = '';
    while (true) {
        $c1 = ord($input{$i++});
        $output .= $itoa64{$c1 >> 2};
        $c1 = ($c1 & 0x03) << 4;
        if ($i >= 16) {
            $output .= $itoa64{$c1};
            break;
        }
        $c2 = ord($input{$i++});
        $c1 |= $c2 >> 4;
        $output .= $itoa64{$c1};
        $c1 = ($c2 & 0x0f) << 2;
        $c2 = ord($input{$i++});
        $c1 |= $c2 >> 6;
        $output .= $itoa64{$c1};
        $output .= $itoa64{$c2 & 0x3f};
    }
    return $output;
}
```

**Differences side by side:**

```
+------+-------------------------+------------------+
| Line | Niels Provos            | OpenWall         |
+------+-------------------------+------------------+
|   18 | $c1 |= $c2 >> 4 & 0x0f; | $c1 |= $c2 >> 4; |
|      |                         |                  |
|   22 | $c1 |= $c2 >> 6 & 0x03; | $c1 |= $c2 >> 6; |
+------+-------------------------+------------------+
```

Do the differences have any effect? do they affect compatibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no difference here. Niels' implementation just goes one step further to verify that the correct bits are set/unset, by using `&` as a bitmask:

```
10010111 >> 4 = 00001001 (OpenWall's outputs this value)
0x0F = 00001111
00001001 & 00001111 = 00001001 (Niels' implementation outputs this value)

11010111 >> 6 = 00000010 (OpenWall's outputs this value)
0x03 = 00000011
00000010 & 00000011 = 00000010 (Niels' implementation outputs this value)
```

Notice that `0x0F` masks all but the four rightmost bits, whereas `0x03` masks all but the two rightmost bits. Then consider that the shifts leave 4 and 2 bits remaining respectively, on an 8-bit value.

As such, as long as `$c2` is an 8-bit value, the bitmask is unnecessary and the two implementations are equal.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to related info: This [Hacker Noon article](https://hackernoon.com/the-bcrypt-protocol-is-kind-of-a-mess-4aace5eb31bd) discusses how base64 is used in different bcrypt implementations, esp. that bcrypt uses a non-standard base64 (section "Issue 1: Non-Standard encoding").

> ...the used encoding for the salt and hash is a strange non-standard Base64 dialect. Wikipedia lists it in its article in the section “Radix-64 applications” and originates it to crypt(3) with seemingly only modern usage being bcrypt. Granted, it has the same, but permutated alphabet, still making it incompatible to RFC 4648. This makes implementing it unnecessarily harder and more error prone, since practically all programming languages have a RFC 4648 implementation of Base64 or support for it.